# No sound on after installing Big Sur

Tags: bug, big-sur, sound-volume

Device: MBP 13 2017 no Touch Bar

Problem: can't hear anything. Sound is not working at all

[image: Laptop specs]
[image: No output devices]

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far. Suggestions: reboot, NPRAM/VRAM reset, Safe mode, run diagnostic mode (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255)... try different apps for playback, connect a speaker and then disconnect. Disconnect all peripherals,... It sounds - so far - like you have done nothing so there is no hint at what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sound is working again after reboot.